# Vue.js rangeslider mousedrag not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, rangeslider

I'm trying to get my rangeslider in vue.js to work. For some reason draggin by using mobile or mouse is not working. Clicking is working perfectly.

Any clues?

Here is my RangeSlider.vue file

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      min: {
        required: true,
      },
      max: {
        required: true,
      },
      suffix: {
        required: false,
        default: '',
      },
      name: {
        required: true,
      }
    },

    data() {
      return {
        dragging: false,
        value: 0,
        id: '',
      };
    },

    mounted() {
      $(window).mouseup(e => {
        if (this.dragging) {
          this.dragging = false;
        }
      });

      $(window).mousemove(e => {
        if (this.dragging) {
          this.move(e);
        }
      });

      this.id = this.makeid();
    },

    methods: {
      drag() {
        this.dragging = true;
      },

      drop() {
        this.dragging = false;
      },

      move(e) {
        const sliderPos = $('#' + this.id + ' .range-slider-slider').offset().left;
        const sliderWidth = $('#' + this.id + ' .range-slider-slider').width();
        const min = 0;
        const max = sliderWidth - $('#' + this.id + ' .range-slider-handle').width();

        const position = Math.min(max, Math.max((e.pageX - 25) - sliderPos, min));

        $('#' + this.id + ' .range-slider-handle').css({
          left: position + 'px',
        });

        const n = this.max - this.min;
        const k = position / sliderWidth;
        const v = Number(Math.ceil(n * k)) + Number(this.min);

        if (v == this.max) {
          this.value = v + '+';
        } else {
          this.value = v;
        }
      },

      makeid() {
          var text = "";
          var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

          for( var i=0; i < 8; i++ )
              text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

          return text;
      }
    }
  };
</script>

<template>
  <div class="range-slider" :id="id">
    <input v-model="value" type="hidden" :name="name">
    <div class="range-slider-slider" @click="move"></div>
    <div :class="['range-slider-handle', dragging ? 'active' : '']" @mousedown="drag" @mouseup="drop"><span class="ranger-slider-label">{{ value }} {{ suffix }}</span></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here is my form-group

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="experience">{{ trans('position.experience') }}</label>
    <range-slider name="experience" min="0" max="10"></range-slider>
</div>
```

Comment: why is there a `:` in this `<div :class="['ran`

Comment: @CallumLinington because class attribute is binded to specific value/expression - it's shorther way for `v-bind` directive.

Comment: Are you getting any error in console, when you try to drag ?

Comment: @BelminBedak No no error in the console at all.

Comment: I never worked with Range slider, but you are listening for click event and then tigger move method, why you didn't try to listen on dragstart or drag event ?

Comment: Ok i got this working by changing the mounted() method this.dragging = true.